# About the phrase Balian has in his workshop

Tags: dialogue, origin, kingdom-of-heaven

There is a [quote in *Kingdom of Heaven*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320661/quotes?item=qt0324984), when Balian explains to Liam Neeson's character the meaning of a phrase he has carved in wood in his workshop.

He says the meaning is "What man is a man who does not make the world better."

I have two questions regarding this phrase:

1. In what language and alphabet is the phrase carved in the wood? Can you reproduce it here with a great degree of confidence?
2. Was this phrase invented for the movie, or does it have a historical precedence? Does it appear elsewhere in literature or history?

Comment: The phrase is found on the entry-way to a [masonic lodge](http://goodnightraleigh.com/2010/06/the-masonic-lodge-americas-smallest-naval-base/) in America; http://goodnightraleigh.com/uploaded_images/masons-400x266.jpg. I'm unsure whether this pre-dates the film

Comment: "Nemo vir est qui mundum non reddat meliorem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [film script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/The_Kingdom_of_Heaven.pdf) indicates that it's Latin

> ODO, still eating his apple, sees: a LATIN PHRASE CUT DEEP INTO A
>   BLACKENED BEAM (or painted, like a frieze, onto the plaster). He
>   points with the sword.

That being the case, the translation would be

> ***Nemo vir est qui mundum non reddat meliorem***

[image]

Comment: Did you find the script online? Could you ad a reference to it? Thanks!

Comment: @jotadepicas - Done and done

Comment: As far as I can tell, the phrase was invented for the movie. I've seen references on wikiquotes suggesting that the DVD commentary confirms this but I've not yet located a copy.

Comment: You might also want to adress the 2nd question, though. In its current form this seems to provide only half an answer (the less important/interesting half even, but that might be subjective).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - In the absence of a copy of the DVD commentary,  I'm not in a position to add anything further. I've certainly not found anything that indicates that the quote pre-dates the movie but lack of evidence does not equal proof.

Comment: Well, mentioning that in the answer would at least show effort in regards to answering the 2nd question.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Comments behind a fan-sourced wiki article are about the lowest form of 'evidence' imaginable and my inability to locate the quote doesn't speak to anything other than my lack of ability to locate the quote.

Comment: But it would show that you didn't just downright ignore half of the question. But nevermind.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - [Partial Answers](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) deserve love too...